# Is it possible to know a user logged in on Ubuntu instantly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

In fact, I am trying to restrict access to some websites for different users. I asked the question:   [Restrict access to some websites for different users](https://superuser.com/questions/791848/restrict-access-to-some-websites-for-different-users).

The given answer is ok; but as the owner of answer says, it works if users are locally logged in. That is; if the user logs out and logs in, restrictions are no more valid.

So, I decided to run a script including the *iptables* commands for restrictions at every log in event. I want to know whether it is possible to know instantly the user logs in.

Comment: Those iptables rules should work even if the user logs out and logs back in.

Comment: I run the command as root and switch to the user that I want to restrict whose access. Restrictions apply then. But as I state, after a new log in event; it is not working. Maybe there are further problems?

Comment: Do you reboot the computer? `iptables` rules don't persist between restarts.

Comment: I tried both reboot and sign out/sign in. In both cases it didn't work anymore.

Comment: After adding the block rule, can you log out and log back in (not reboot), and then can you run `sudo iptables -L OUTPUT` and post the results in your question? This should print out what is still in the firewall. Logging in/out shouldn't mess with that, but I'm curious if the rule is being deleted somehow.